# Filter shows "true" instead of wanted labels in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, function, leaflet, collision

Filter certain numbers out to show as labels in Leaflet. The code below do filter correctly but it does not show the correct labels, it shows "true" on the map instead of the wanted numbers 650 to 699.
What changes is needed to display the properties labels instead of "true" from this filtration?

```
var local_points = new L.layerGroup();

    function local (feature){
        var filter = (feature.properties.local >= 650 && feature.properties.local < 699)
        return filter;
    };

var collisionlocal = L.LayerGroup.collision({margin:5});

$.getJSON("/geodata/localID_points.geojson", function(json) {

var points = L.geoJSON.collision(null, {
    pointToLayer: function(feature,latlng){
    label3s = String('<span class="textLabelclass3small">' + local(feature) + '</span>')
return new L.marker(latlng, {
        icon:createLabelIcon("textLabelclass3small",label3s)
        });
        }
    });

    var createLabelIcon = function(labelClass,labelText){
        return L.divIcon({ 
            className: labelClass,
            html: labelText
            });
        };

points.addData(json);
collisionlocal.addLayer(points);
collisionlocal.addTo(local_points);
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the filter to the geoJson call and not in the text:

```
var points = L.geoJSON.collision(null, {
    filter: local,
    pointToLayer: function(feature,latlng){
        label3s = String('<span class="textLabelclass3small">' + feature.properties.local + '</span>')
        return new L.marker(latlng, {
           icon:createLabelIcon("textLabelclass3small",label3s)
        });
     }
});
```